# Pascal Synaser in Linux - SendString trouble - works fine in Windows

Tags: linux, serial-port, freepascal, beagleboneblack

I'm quite new to pascal but a very experienced developer in many other languages, I'm working on a project using the BeagleBone Black (an ARM based single board system similar to a Pi) and I need some serial communications. I've found across most languages support for this is now pretty poor, and while I was using Java the Serial Libraries just don't work on ARM based systems.

I've made one windows tool in Pascal using Synaser and was really impressed, so I have started creating some test code for my Beagle, I've got code that compiles on my Beagle (using just FPC rather than full Lazarus install), I had to remove a few baudrate definitions from the Synaser unit to make that compile but that was fine.

So now to the problem, the device (a USB zigbee) I am communicating with requires a CR to be sent after each command. I am using the SendString command and I have this working fine by sending #13#10 on the end of my message on windows, and have also discovered Synaser has CR, LF & CRLF constants built in, so have tried those in Linux but nothing I do seems to send and message. I have made sure my hardware is functioning by using minicom and sending messages between the beagle and my laptop. I have also used some pascal code to listen for messages and can confirm that I can receive messages using pascal and Synaser on the Beagle.

I'm out of ideas now, any help would be appreciated!

This code works perfectly on windows and compiles on linux but does nothing

```
procedure ABeagleTest.DoRun;
begin
  ser:=TBlockSerial.Create;
  try
    ser.Connect('/dev/ttyUSB0'); //ComPort
    Sleep(1000);
    ser.config(19200, 8, 'N', SB1, False, False);
      writeln('USB Device Connected');
    Sleep(1000);
    ser.SendString('AT+BCAST:00,Hello World!'+#13#10);

  finally
    ser.free;
  end;

  // stop program loop
  Terminate;
end;
```

I'll happily post anything else useful such as my serial reading code, but as I know it works I felt is wasn't helpful right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs to be in `dialout` group to have permission accessing `/dev/ttyUSB*`. Logout then log back in after adding your current user to that group, reboot if necessary (shouldn't be, but I don't have experience in every Linux distro, there could be chances it's required). Otherwise, simply run as root (with sudo), it should already have the permission.

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid in desperation I've reached the point of "stuff it I'm logging in as root" so I don't think any user privileges are causing the problem.

Comment: have you checked and proved it yourself? no user may access any serial device if it's not in dialout group. no other way around to overcome this, it's a security feature.

Comment: well I can read from the port so I'm pretty happy I'm connected, and I can use the device fully using minicom, how else can I prove it?

Comment: but it doesn't work for writing, right? why don't you just try once with sudo or add your user to dialout group? just to ensure if that's really your problem or not.

Comment: Thanks I really have laboured this idea to death now, I've even created a new user and added that to dialout etc and unfortunately there's no change to the results, still able to read and not write. Thanks again